# Older home soap dish fell off tile wall and left a hole - how can I fix it?

Tags: walls

In my home I have a tile wall where the soap dish has fallen out and left a hole. Can I put a tile on top of tile to cover the hole instead of putting plastic against the hole to keep the inside from getting wet?

Comment: Can you add a picture?

Comment: `whole` means "complete" ..... `hole` means "an opening"

Comment: @jsotola phone voice recognition doesn't know that semicolon it also tends to cause run-on sentences when people don't know how to say.. oh nice job Google. Facepalm

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Even with someone editing your post for clarity, it's tough to know what you're dealing with. As @fixer1234 said, a picture would really help.

Comment: use liquid nails to stick it back on, or retile it.